# show iframe only for trusted sites

Tags: iframe

I have a code which generates iframe which user can embed on his site.

I want to show my iframe only on particular sites. 
How can I do this?

For example:
I can give a unique key to user and use this key on server side.
But another user can get this key an use it.

Is there simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

The referrer solution is not robust in any way. Referrer is something "said" by the browser it can be manually overridden as said above, moreover anyone could simply use a proxy and reintegrate the iframe.

So, basically, it depends on how much code can be put on the "Trusted server".

If you can, use one time tokens. Trusted server gets a list of tokens from server having the iframe. The url served by the trusted server contains the token which will be invalidated upon serving the content of the iframe. This does mean that there is a "write" for each read. And tokens will take some space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the referrer response-header as described in the HTTP standard.

Though expert users (the übergeeks/browsermodders) know how to omit this. You <strike>should</strike> may **not** do this for security reasons.